# Adding write access for low integrity processes under .Net

Tags: c#, .net, windows, security, acl

I'm creating an FileSecurity for file creation that should have an write access also for low integrity processes.

```
FileSecurity fileAcl = new FileSecurity();

// add everyone
IdentityReference sid = new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, null);
FileSystemAccessRule rule = new FileSystemAccessRule(sid, FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow);
fileAcl.AddAccessRule(rule);

// add restricted
sid = new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.RestrictedCodeSid, null);
rule = new FileSystemAccessRule(sid, FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow);
fileAcl.AddAccessRule(rule);

// add low integrity level rights

// ???
```

If someone knows how to do it without invoking C API I would appreciate it, otherwise I'll have to rework to use it entirely.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this in .NET code? I'd also like to be able to create low-integrity writeable folders/files from .net code.

Comment: I made C glue to do that for me.

Comment: @Yankeen, can you share any sample or point me somewhere with a c example for this? Thanks!

Comment: This blog post including pinvoke calls may help: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/08/27/writing-to-files-from-low_2d00_integrity-processes-in-c-sharp-dotnet.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if they are exposed in .NET, but the [integrity levels themselves are also well-known SIDs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379649.aspx).  You should also read the [Mandatory Integrity Control documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb648648.aspx) to understand how to use them.

Comment: Hi Luke,
the sids are known, but the integrity labels are part of sacl, so cannot use the api exposed by MS that offeres to add parsed identities to dacl. I need the binary representation of acl so the more I think about it might be best way to include it as an array created in C app instead of creating it in .net.