# Create folder that's writeable for Low-Integrity processes using WiX installer MSI

Tags: wix, windows-installer

As part of my MSI installer I'd like to create a folder that's writeable by low-integrity processes (e.g. Internet Explorer extensions running within IE Protected Mode). I can write to `c:\users\{username}\AppData\LocalLow\here` but for various reasons I'd like to create a folder like `C:\ProgramData\{myApp}\LocalLow\here`.

Any way I can achieve this within WiX?

By Low-integrity write I'm referring to stuff like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3226886/adding-write-access-for-low-integrity-processes-under-net) and [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/08/27/writing-to-files-from-low_2d00_integrity-processes-in-c-sharp-dotnet.aspx).

Comment: Translate those blog articles into system configuration requirements and I can articulate how you would do it in wix.

Answer (score 0):

Use the directory property CommonAppDataFolder to reference C:\ProgramData.  Create child directory elements and use a CreateFolder element to create the folder.  Finally use the Permission element to open the permissions up. (Everyone Full Control?)

Comment: Unfortuantely the Low-Integrity stuff is a bit more complex than simple permissions - I'll add more info to the question